# Why do I get an error while compiling this code?

Tags: c++, opengl

Whenever I try to include any other.h file other than the glut.h I get an       error while compiling . What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <type_traits> 
#include <iostream>

//using namespace std; 
int h=500;
int w=1000;
int x=1;
float a=0;
float b=0;
int s=35;
float speedy=0.2;
float speedx=0.15;
float rate=0.0002;
bool touchright=false;
bool escaped=false;
```

the error is:

> `"Error    1   error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs    d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\stdlib.h 360 1   OpenGL2DTemplate"`

Comment: What exact error do you get? Provide full error traceback and more code

Comment: When you have an error message, you need to specify the *exact* text of that message here.

Comment: Props for proper formatting and quickly adding missing info.  This makes it so much easier to help...